# Mapear relacionamentos com Fluent API

Tags: c#, entity-framework-6, entidade-relacionamento, fluent-api

Tenho três classes simples de cidade, estado e país. Percebi que simplesmente declarando uma propriedade do tipo `Estado` na classe `Cidade` a chave estrangeira é gerada corretamente. Gostaria de saber como fazer esses mapeamentos na mão, fico mais seguro, e se minha preocupação é à toa, fica a dúvida da necessidade de ter as opções de mapear na mão.

Seguem as entidades:

```
public class CidadeEntity {
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Nome { get; set; }
    //public int EstadoId { get; set; }
    public virtual EstadoEntity Estado { get; set; }
}

public class EstadoEntity{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Sigla { get; set; }
    public string Nome { get; set; }
    public virtual IList<CidadeEntity> CidadeLista { get; set; }
    //public byte EstadoPaisId { get; set; }
    public virtual PaisEntity Pais { get; set; }
}

public class PaisEntity {
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Sigla { get; set; }
    public string Nome { get; set; }
    public virtual IList<EstadoEntity> EstadoLista { get; set; }
}
```

Meus mapeamentos:

```
public CidadeMap() {
    ToTable("Cidade");
    HasKey(c => c.Id);
    Property(p => p.Nome)
        .IsRequired()
        .HasColumnType("varchar")
        .HasMaxLength(120);
    //HasRequired(f => f.Estado).WithMany(p => p.CidadeLista).HasForeignKey(p => p.EstadoId);
}

public EstadoMap() {
    ToTable("Estado");
    HasKey(c => c.Id);
    Property(p => p.Sigla).IsRequired().HasColumnType("char").HasMaxLength(5);
    Property(p => p.Nome).IsRequired().HasColumnType("varchar").HasMaxLength(75);
    //Ignore(p => p.EstadoPaisId);
    //Relacionamentos
    HasRequired(p => p.CidadeLista).WithRequiredPrincipal().Map(p => p.MapKey("EstadoId"));
}

public PaisMap() {
    ToTable("Pais");
    HasKey(c => c.Id);
    Property(p => p.Sigla)
        .HasColumnType("varchar")
        .HasMaxLength(5);
    Property(p => p.Nome)
        .HasColumnType("varchar")
        .HasMaxLength(50);
}
```

Contexto com BD:

```
[DbConfigurationType(typeof(MySql.Data.Entity.MySqlEFConfiguration))]    
public class DataContext:DbContext {
    public DataContext():base("ConexaoBD") {

    }

    public DbSet<PaisEntity> Pais { get; set; }

    public DbSet<EstadoEntity> Estado { get; set; }

    public DbSet<CidadeEntity> Cidade { get; set; }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder) {
        modelBuilder.Configurations.Add(new PaisMap());
        modelBuilder.Configurations.Add(new EstadoMap());
        modelBuilder.Configurations.Add(new CidadeMap());
        base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
    }
}
```

No `EstadoMap` fiz o mapeamento com `Cidade` (`HasRequired(p => p.CidadeLista).WithRequiredPrincipal().Map(p => p.MapKey("EstadoId"))`) mas ficou duplicado porque gerou o meu e o mapeamento automático (esse sem `nullable: false`), vi que dá pra fazer esse mapeamento pela cidade também (`HasRequired(p => p.Estado).WithRequiredDependent();`), mas não deu certo e não percebi se tem diferença do Estado pra Cidade e ao contrário. Não sei se estou fazendo as coisas de forma correta.

Comment: vou preparar um exemplo e já posto para você

Comment: Se possível coloca seu Context também

Comment: Coloquei o contexto, apesar de ser com MySql acredito não fazer diferença, acaha que faz? Valeu pela ajuda

Comment: Pois então, o exemplo que fiz usa SQL Server, nunca testei com MySql, mas acredito que deverá funcionar da mesma forma.

Comment: Funcionou blz :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Então, fiz algumas adaptações principalmente nas suas classes:

**CidadeMap**

Mantive

```
HasRequired(a => a.Estado).WithMany(a => a.CidadeLista).HasForeignKey(a => a.EstadoId);
```

**EstadoMap**

```
HasRequired(p => p.CidadeLista).WithRequiredPrincipal().Map(p => p.MapKey("EstadoId"));
```

Alterei para

```
HasRequired(a => a.Pais).WithMany(a => a.EstadoLista).HasForeignKey(a => a.PaisId);
```

**CidadeEntity**

Adicionei

```
public int EstadoId { get; set; }
```

**EstadoEntity**

Adicionei

```
public int PaisId { get; set; }
```

Meu contexto ficou da seguinte forma

```
public class ExemploContext : DbContext
    {
        public ExemploContext()
            :base("DefaultConnection")
        {

        }

        public DbSet<EstadoEntity> Estados { get; set; }

        public DbSet<CidadeEntity> Cidades { get; set; }

        public DbSet<PaisEntity> Paises { get; set; }

        protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
        {
            modelBuilder.Configurations.Add(new EstadoMap());
            modelBuilder.Configurations.Add(new CidadeMap());
            modelBuilder.Configurations.Add(new PaisMap());

            base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
        }
    }
```

O código fonte do exemplo você pode pegar [aqui](https://github.com/pablotdv/StackOverflow/tree/master/MapeamentoFluentAPIRelacionamentos)

Não sou muito bom com conceitos, mas na prática o exemplo que dei é como normalmente trabalho com mapeamento de Relacionamentos no EntityFramework usando Fluent API

Comment: Deu certo aqui, valeu cara, nos testes acabei achando que não precisaria de declarar uma propriedade equivalente à Id da classe "pai", aí todos os testes deram errado.